# MVVM and Databinding with UniformGrid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to style the back of a WPF chart with some rectangles. I'm using MVVM, and I need the rectangles to be uniformly sized. When defined via Xaml, this works with a fixed "BucketCount" of 4:

```
<VisualBrush>
  <VisualBrush.Visual>
  <UniformGrid Height="500" Width="500" Rows="1" Columns="{Binding BucketCount}">
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="#22ADD8E6" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#22D3D3D3"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="#22ADD8E6"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Fill="#22D3D3D3"/>
  </UniformGrid>        
 </VisualBrush.Visual>
<VisualBrush>
```

How can I bind my ObservableCollection of Rectangles? There is no "ItemsSource" property on UniformGrid. Do I need to use an ItemsControl? If so, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use ItemsControl to Bind like this. Simple example where ItemsSource is just an `ObservableCollection<Brush>`

```
<VisualBrush>
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBrushes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Height="500" Width="500" Rows="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

**Update**
It works for my usage scenario, but I might be missing something here. Here's the full code I've tried. I get the same result from both

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyBrushes}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Height="500" Width="500" Rows="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!--<UniformGrid Height="500" Width="500" Rows="1" Columns="4">
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="#22ADD8E6" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#22D3D3D3"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="#22ADD8E6"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Fill="#22D3D3D3"/>
                </UniformGrid>-->
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BrushConverter brushConverter = new BrushConverter();
        MyBrushes = new ObservableCollection<Brush>();
        MyBrushes.Add(brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#22ADD8E6") as Brush);
        MyBrushes.Add(brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#22D3D3D3") as Brush);
        MyBrushes.Add(brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#22ADD8E6") as Brush);
        MyBrushes.Add(brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#22D3D3D3") as Brush);
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Brush> MyBrushes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work... I wonder what I could be missing?

Comment: @JP: Didn't you get any result at all or didn't it work the way it was supposed to?

Comment: No result. Nothing shows up. I've checked the binding name so that's not the issue.

Comment: @JP: Uploaded my full sample code. I might have missed something on how you're using this

Comment: Hmm, thanks I'll look it over. If it matters, my VisualBrush is not on a Grid or UniformGrid. It's on the "PlotArea" of a Visifire graph. So maybe it's a Canvas?

Comment: @JP: I don't have Visifire installed so unfortunately I can't test it. I tried it on a Canvas and got the same results as on the Grid so I'm not sure what the problem could be

Comment: If I set "itemsControl.ItemsSource" to "MyBrushes" in the code behind and remove it from the DataContext it works. So it must be a binding issue, as in it can't locate "MyBrushes" from Xaml... any thoughts? Btw, your example worked fine without Visifire involved.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to use a RelativeSource with FindAncestor... not quite sure of the syntax though.

Comment: @JP: It's a little hard to tell since I'm not sure how your xaml looks, maybe if you add some more sample code. The Binding you used in the example where you used Binding BucketCount, did that binding work?

Comment: I toyed around with your example... but I got it to work by adding this: RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:MainWindow}} Thanks for your help!